# Alternativa para Switch dentro de Switch

Tags: c#, if, switch

Estou fazendo uma estrutura de decisão que depende de mais de uma variável, mas a legibilidade e manutenção usando `if` ou `switch` são péssimas.

Quais alternativas e tenho para esse caso?

Exemplo de `switch` aninhados:

```
switch (var1)
{
    case "A":
        switch (var2)
        {
            case 0:
                ...
                break;
            case 1:
                ...
                break;
            case 2:
                ...
                break;
        }
        break;
    case "B":
        switch (var2)
        {
            case 0:
                ...
                break;
            case 1:
                ...
                break;
            case 2:
                ...
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

Na situação real eu estou fazendo um programa estilo *crawler* que a partir de um formulário único precisa replicar as informações preenchendo formulários parecidos em vários outros sites.
No meu formulário eu tenho, por exemplo, um *combo* com dezenas de profissões, daí preciso que a mesma profissão que for escolhida aqui seja mapeada para a opção correspondente do outro site.

A opção que no meu *combo* é `Engenheiro (a)` em um site é `Engenheiro`, em outro é `Engenheiro (outros)`, em outro é `Engenheiro(a)/Arquiteto(a)`, em outro é `Engenheiro/Arquiteto`...

Portanto no caso real, as variáveis que uso no `Switch..Case` são o nome do site que estou mapeando e a opção selecionada no *combo*.

Comment: Que tipo de alternativa você quer? Qual é seu problema? Está apenas achando feio?

Comment: se tem mesmo de ser, extraí o código para funções

Comment: Corrigi o Preciso ( fazer fazer ) uma  :)

Comment: O problema é basicamente ser feio. Eu só coloquei um exemplo porque o código real é *MUITO* maior. Fazer ele não é tão trabalhoso porque fui montando os `switch..case` com _regex_, mas ler ele e dar manutenção está muito ruim. Cadastrar tudo em um banco seria uma alternativa, mas os valores praticamente não vão mudar e o acesso ao banco deixaria mais lento. Pode ser que simplesmente não tem outra opção e terei que viver com isso :(

Comment: Acho que o melhor jeito é extrair cada switch secundário para uma função mais genérica, é que depende muito do caso, com sorte e alguma abstração você consegue até usar essa função novamente, mas está bem vaga sua pergunta então não tem como te ajudar mais do que isso. Sinto muito.

Comment: O `switch()` interno do `case "A":` será igual ao do case "B":?

Comment: Sim, @Randrade os `switch` internos podem ser iguais. Coloquei mais explicação no final da pergunta falando o meu uso real, espero que ajude.

Comment: Neste caso, você pode criar um método que recebe o valor de `var2` e te retorna o valor esperado. Irá passar neste método em cada `switch`, mas para manutenção será muito melhor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

De fato o comando ***switch-case*** é bastante **feio** e quase sempre **dispensável**.

Em vez de usar este comando ou longas cadeias de *if-elseif-elseif...*, você pode usar dicionários.

No seu caso, você preencheria um dicionário de dicionários, com a seguinte semântica:

```
profissão -> site -> profissão naquele site
```

Assim, em vez de fazer um código imperativo longo, confuso, feio e de difícil manutenção  como este:

```
switch (profissao_selecionada)
{
    case "Engenheiro(a)":
        switch (site_selecionado)
        {
            case "site A":
                profissao_no_outro_site = "Engenheiro/Arquiteto";
                break;
            case "site B":
                profissao_no_outro_site = "Engenheiro (outros)";
                break;
        }
        break;
    case "Astronauta":
        switch (site_selecionado)
        {
            case "site A":
                profissao_no_outro_site = "Cosmonauta";
                break;
            case "site B":
                profissao_no_outro_site = "Espaçonauta";
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

você pode associar profissão e site de uma forma mais declarativa:

```
profissoes["Engenheiro(a)"]["site A"] = "Engenheiro/Arquiteto";
profissoes["Engenheiro(a)"]["site B"] = "Engenheiro (outros)";

profissoes["Astronauta"]["site A"] = "Cosmonauta";
profissoes["Astronauta"]["site B"] = "Espaçonauta";
```

E então, **em apenas uma única linha, sem nenhum *switch-case***, você verifica como a profissão selecionada no combo é definida em determinado site, mais ou menos assim:

```
profissao_no_outro_site = profissoes[profissao_selecionada][site_selecionado];
```

Veja que você pode usar o próprio dicionário para popular as profissões no combo em vez de replicá-las no combo e no código, de modo a **dar manutenção nos itens em um único lugar**.

## Exemplo completo

Se ficou alguma dúvida, veja este exemplo funcional completo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> profissoes;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var engenheiro = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        engenheiro["site A"] = "Engenheiro";
        engenheiro["site B"] = "Engenheiro (outros)";
        engenheiro["site C"] = "Engenheiro(a)/Arquiteto(a)";

        var astronauta = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        astronauta["site A"] = "Cosmonauta";
        astronauta["site B"] = "Espaçonauta";
        astronauta["site C"] = "Lunático";

        profissoes = new Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>();
        profissoes["Engenheiro(a)"] = engenheiro;
        profissoes["Astronauto(a)"] = astronauta;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var profissao in profissoes)
            comboProfissoes.Items.Add(profissao.Key);
    }
    private void seleciona_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var profissaoSelecionada = (String)comboProfissoes.SelectedItem;
        var mensagem = "A profissão " + profissaoSelecionada 
            + " no site B é " + profissoes[profissaoSelecionada]["site B"];
        MessageBox.Show(mensagem);
    }
}
```

Cujo "output" é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Armazenando código complexo no dicionário

E se em cada bloco ***case*** você precisasse executar algumas linhas de código em vez de simplesmente setar uma variável como eu fiz no exemplo acima? O dicionário ainda é a solução!

No exemplo acima, usamos o dicionário para armazenar a legenda da profissão em outro site, mas podemos usá-lo para armazenar qualquer objeto e não apenas strings. Ou seja: podemos adicionar blocos de código no dicionário para serem executados em momento oportuno, dispensando o *switch-case* em praticamente qualquer situação.

Desde que o dicionário suporta **objetos** e quase tudo em C# é um objeto, existem várias maneiras de se armazenar blocos de código no dicionário: você pode armazenar *actions*, *functions*, pode definir seus próprios *delegates*, *interfaces*, classes abstratas... O céu é o limite :D

Observe que a própria chave do dicionário também pode ser qualquer objeto, expadindo ainda mais os horizontes.

#### Um pequeno exemplo

Vamos supor que aquele mesmo blocão *switch* lá de cima faça mais coisas além de simplesmente setar uma variável:

```
switch (profissao_selecionada)
{
    case "Engenheiro(a)":
        switch (site_selecionado)
        {
            case "site A":
                // faz um trabalho muito específico aqui
                break;
            case "site B":
                // faz outro trabalho específico aqui
                break;
        }
        break;
    case "Astronauta":
        switch (site_selecionado)
        {
            case "site A":
                // mais trabalhos complexos
                break;
            case "site B":
                // outros serviços impensáveis
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

O que você tem a fazer é encapsular cada bloco de código em métodos com uma assinatura comum:

```
void Metodo_01()
{
    // faz um trabalho muito específico aqui
}
void Metodo_02()
{
    // faz outro trabalho específico aqui
}
void Metodo_03()
{
    // mais trabalhos complexos
}
void Metodo_04()
{
    // outros serviços impensáveis
}
```

Daí você declara um *delegate* com esta assinatura comum (ou usa os delegates nativos do .Net, se preferir):

```
delegate void ProcessadorProfissoes();
```

E então preenche o dicionário como antes, só que agora adicionando métodos nele em vez de adicionar strings:

```
var processadorEngenheiro = new Dictionary<String, ProcessadorProfissoes>();
processadorEngenheiro["site A"] = Metodo_01;
processadorEngenheiro["site B"] = Metodo_02;

var processadorAstronauta = new Dictionary<String, ProcessadorProfissoes>();
processadorAstronauta["site A"] = Metodo_03;
processadorAstronauta["site B"] = Metodo_04;

processadorProfissoes = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, ProcessadorProfissoes>>();
processadorProfissoes["Engenheiro(a)"] = processadorEngenheiro;
processadorProfissoes["Astronauta"] = processadorAstronauta;
```

Agora, para executar o bloco de código referente à profissão e site selecionados, basta esta simples linha, sem *switch-case*, sem *if*...:

```
processadorProfissoes[profissaoSelecionada][siteSelecionado]();
```

## Conclusão

Código com blocos ***switch-case*** e longos blocos ***if-else if*** na maioria das vezes podem ser melhor expressados através de dicionários ou combinação de dicionários, simplificando a manutenção do código.

Nos exemplos desta resposta, foram armazenados no dicionário strings e métodos com assinatura simples; mas podemos armazenar qualquer tipo de objeto, podendo ter então métodos com assinaturas complexas, retornando valores, ou objetos completos recheados de estado para poderem executar trabalhos complexos.

Answer (score 1):

Poderia deixar com valores predefinido

```
$valores = array(
    'carro' => array('item1' => 'pneu', 'item2' => 'pneu','item3' => 'pneu'),

    'moto' => array('item1' =>'gidao', 'item2' => 'pneu', 'item3' =>'quadro'),

    'caminhao' => array('item1' => 'volante', 'item2' =>'banco', 'item3' =>'porta'),
```

);

echo $valores[$tipo][$item];

OBS: não tinha reparado que a pergunta era para C#. Como já respondi, entenda apenas a ideia.

Comment: Que é uma ótima idéia; a mesma que já foi dada na outra resposta, inclusive.